# Can the snapcraft and snap-package tags please be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Since [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) is the tool to build snap packages, the two tags [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) and [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) should be the same thing, if possible.

Having both tags in addition to [ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-core) and [snappy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snappy) gives us who want to help answer all `snapd`/`snapcraft` questions more places to watch.

Please let me know what you think.

*Update:* as some questions arose during the discussion so far, I thought I'd add them to the question as well to make it clearer.

`snapd` powers Ubuntu Core systems, but is also available on Ubuntu Desktop systems by default since 16.04 LTS. It allows the user to install self-contained, confined applications from the store. Compared with traditional .deb packages, they

- are more secure, as they make use of technologies like `apparmor` and `seccomp`
- allow app developers to upload them to the store directly where they are automatically reviewed and published instantly
- give app developers the opportunity to bundle dependencies and thus take care of the entire stack
- can be made available in multiple release channel in the store, so you could track `edge` for a given snap, and use the default (`stable` for another)

The first release where Ubuntu Core with snaps was introduced was 15.04. Over time, `snapd` will be used on the phone and other places too.

`snapcraft` is the tool with which you can build snaps. This is entirely separate from the `.deb` packaging practices. The underlying tools are different and the place where they are published too. Both types of packages can be installed from the new Software Center, but the technologies are very different.

The reality on askubuntu.com today is that [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) is used for traditional packaging and [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) (and [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package)) are just used for creating snaps.

It would help the `snapd`/`snapcraft` developers (they are mostly watching the queues of questions right now) a lot, if [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) and [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) were merged.

Comment: Agreed. It is unessecary for them to be different.

Comment: It seems to me that they are different things. [tag:snapcraft] is a tool to build snaps and [tag:snap-package] is the actual package. Similar to "debuild" and "debian-package".

Comment: In my mind it'd make more sense to use the tag `ubuntu-core` for software which doesn't work on Ubuntu Core.

Comment: The way the tags are used today, `snapcraft` and `snap-package` are almost synonymous.

Comment: snapcraft is using snapcraft to build snaps, and snap-package would be using/installing a snap-package from a user perspective - they likely wouldn't even think to use "snapcraft" in that context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These tags are getting too confusing and pedantic, we should:

- Rename [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) to [snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap), easy to remember and covers everything from the snaps themselves to snapcraft, this allows the core team to subscribe to just one tag so they can answer questions.
- Alias [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) to [snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap).
- Leave [snappy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snappy) aliased to [ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-core), which is a pure snappy system.

Comment: That's the best compromise. I agree. Thanks!

Comment: This has been completed

Answer (score 2):

IMO: [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) ≡ [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) ∩ [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging), since [snap-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) alone could be used for questions unrelated to actually building snaps. So if the tags are merged, questions currently using [snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) should be examined to see if they fit [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) as well.

On a side note, the [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) wiki should now say "Debian or snap packages".

Comment: `snapcraft` is triple-bonded to `snap-package`, which plays horseshoes with `packaging`? Could you please explain in English for us non-mathematical types?

Comment: Agreed, I see no benefit in splitting this up. There would probably questions left about hacking on `snapcraft` itself, I suppose.

Similarly, extending and improving traditional packaging tools, would still count as `packaging` activities in my mind.

Comment: @NickWeinberg ∩ means "Intersection" in set theory. `snapcraft` is the intersection of `snap-package` and `packaging` , i.e, `snapcrsft` contains common elements from both `snap-package` and `packaging` (But it does not mean all questions are common).

Comment: I don't think that this describes reality in Ubuntu. `packaging` is used for .deb packaging and snapping software is quite different. That's also what I've noticed on askubuntu.com.

Comment: @dholbach How long has snap been around? It's my guess that packaging has been around a long time, and its wiki says deb because we don't deal with anything else here. I don't know about you, but it says on http://snapcraft.io/create/: "Snapcraft is a snappy packaging tool." Also on https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/: "Snapcraft is a build and packaging tool which helps you package your software as a snap."

Comment: Why is this question even relevant? `snapcraft` has been around for about a year and is here to stay. I have discussed the question of aliasing the two tags with the majority of people who work on `snapd` and `snapcraft` - they're in favour of merging the two tags as they're the same thing in reality and we'd prefer not having to review two queues of questions.

Comment: @dholbach why are you asking me? You're the OP.

Comment: The OP? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @dholbach you're the person who posted this question. If you think there's no point to the question, delete it and move on instead of commenting repeatedly on my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just didn't expect the question of how old snapcraft/snappy was. I'll try to clarify my question again.